# Click on webelement which isn't active

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Here I have a form to fill with data and after that I need to hit the add patient button. The Form is divided into four sections and these section are displayed in tabs. One of the tab is loaded by default and I could operate on the fields in this tab without any problem but when I try to click on the  other tab (Contact Info) to fill all the fields in this tab I’m facing the issue. Could you please help me

```
WebElement contact = driver.findElement(By.id("personal-contact-info"));
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(contact).click().perform();
WebElement Address = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceholder_ContentPlaceholder_AddPatientForm_TextBox8"));
Address.sendKeys("India");
```

The HTML Code is

```
<div id="personal-contact-info" class="input-form">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="one-half-container first-container">
      <div class="container">
        <dl>
          <dt>Address</dt>
          <dd>
            <input class="input input-address" name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceholder$ContentPlaceholder$AddPatientForm$TextBox8" type="text" id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceholder_ContentPlaceholder_AddPatientForm_TextBox8" />
          </dd>
          <dd>
            <input class="input input-address" name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceholder$ContentPlaceholder$AddPatientForm$TextBox9" type="text" id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceholder_ContentPlaceholder_AddPatientForm_TextBox9" />
          </dd>
        </dl>
      </div>
```

Comment: Please provide more details to solve this issue. What exactly goes wrong and which elements are inactive (and why)?

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple Tabs in the same Window it is possible, that you have to use the Webdriver.switchTo() Method, to get into the right Tab. Have You tried this?

Would be sth like this. This is to switch to the Parent of the actual Tab

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent()
```